# What to do if refusing recruiters bluntly doesn't work anymore

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment

I have currently a job that I, for the first time of my employment history, really enjoy and I will probably be staying here for some year. I got this job through an online job search website. Upon being hired, I changed the settings of that account so that possible recruiters will know that I am now not actively looking for a job.

Then one of my regular working days, a female recruiter phoned me and asking if I am willing to have a phone interview. I asked where they got my contact information, and they said that they got it from that website. I politely said that I am not looking for a job (like what is stated on my account) and politely  declined her offer, but she insisted the interview. Since I'm on my break, I allow it, just to test if I can still manage to do a decent interview.

Things on the interview gets random sometimes, and the I always point out to her that I am not looking for a job. After some 15 minutes, they asked me when is the date I can start to work. Wow, just wow. That is when I became angry and tell her that **I AM NOT LOOKING FOR A JOB AT THE MOMENT**. Then I ended the call.

A day after, the same number called but a different caller. The caller asked for apologies his fellow recruiter done yesterday, and I said, it's alright, apology accepted, and I explained my side. And after a while he insisted if I want to work to their company and it goes on and on like the previous day.

After I blocked that number, they managed to use another number to recruit me. My coworkers are now making this as a laughing matter and even my superiors, instead of being threatened to the fact some company wants to recruit one of their *[precious]* employee, found me shouting to my phone, hilarious.

I found this annoying and serious to the point **[ that after one week and this continues, ]** I will report this to the authorities. This is the 4th incident.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention they also keep sending messages on my personal email.

Comment: Before escalating this to new heights (authorities and such), maybe just try and be as uninteresting as you can be. A blunt "I am not looking for a job right now", repeated ad nauseam should make things clear. No explanations, no answering questions, just the same sentence, over and over again. After all, they're looking to get something out of the call and if you don't give it to them, why whould they try indefinitely?

Comment: Can't you just simply hang up ? I know I would. It's very unprofessional, but professionalism went out the door when they started behaving like that. Also, what country are you in ?

Comment: Third and fourth incident: When I answered and I heard, "Hi, Im Ms. X from Company Y and I......", automatically end the call

Comment: You need to learn to relax. Two - three calls and you loose your temper? Just tell them no and hang up if they don't get it.

Comment: @Lasse, I'm busy lately specially on those times they've call, so yeah, I need to relax. Especially on that one time they try to call when we are having an adhoc meeting with my superiors, they keep on teasing me up to the next day regarding the interview... :-)

Comment: Oops...can someone else relate to this story ? I know that headhunters are cheeky enough to call at the company but simple recruiters *which still insist on an interview* ?

Comment: Why do you attend calls from recruiters in the presence of your superiors, *especially* when you are not looking for a job?

Comment: @MaskedMan that's an adhoc meeting, they went to my cubicle and start to have a discussion. That is when they used a different number. It's like 10 seconds call and the moment I heard their company name, I instantly ended the call. And the superior just then smiled and so on.

Comment: "I politely said that I am not looking for a job ... and politely declined her offer, but she insisted the interview. Since I'm on my break, **I allow it**..." - I think this was where the mistake was made. If you say no, you have to stick to your guns, as it were. The suggestions to "just say no" are correct. Just politely say the same thing each time they say something and they'll eventually give up. Don't get excited or act angry! The people on the other end may sense your anger as some sort of challenge or break from the monotony of their job - it may make them want to call you *more*.

Comment: +1 to Brandin, but also they have to be told to not call again. Hanging up on them alone gives them no information - maybe you were busy, in a meeting etc. etc. and they should try again at a better time. Telling them not to is a key piece of information.

Comment: You say no, but they get you to do a phone interview, so now they know your mind can be changed. Change your mindset. No one gets to call you on the phone and insist on anything. They can only ask. Don't get upset. Hang-up. Most people go away when they're ignored.

Comment: Related: [What is the proper way to deal with a recruiter who calls during work hours?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-a-recruiter-who-calls-during-work-hours)

Comment: If you're in a meeting, even an ad-hoc one, you shouldn't even answer the phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop recruiters from contacting me?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/how-do-i-stop-recruiters-from-contacting-me)

Comment: If this really bothers you, you could always change your phone number. Changing phone number is free in the US if you tell your phone provider you have a stalker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next time they call, be super friendly. Tell them that you don't want to change jobs. If they want to talk to you after that, ask them for their billing information to send them an invoice for the time they need talking to you. Be adamant to not talk to them any further without that information.

At least for various types of marketeers, that normally ends the conversation quick and decisively.

Comment: I like this idea. Now, I, more than ever, is _really eager_ for them to call me for the 5th time!

Answer (score 7):

Step one: Remove your info from that one particular job search site.

Step two: Remove your phone info from the resumes you post on all the other job search sites. That limits all the future contacts to only using email. Also don't include your phone number on your profile

Step three: Never respond to emails when you are not even thinking about looking for a job.

Step Four: When they call again. Politely tell them to stop calling and to take you off their list. Then hang up.

Step Five: If they continue to call, remind them you have asked to be removed from the list. And that at this point you will be recommending that coworkers and friends never work with the firm.

Don't let them talk you into talking longer. They cold called you and got you to stay on the phone for 15 minutes. When the call should have lasted 15 seconds.

Reporting them to the authorities may be more difficult. In the US they may be able to argue that they have a business relationship with you. They spent 15 minutes recruiting you for a job and you almost took it.  The next day you did it again.

Comment: Just want to add there are some job search sites that don't let you remove your phone number (they use it for marketing purposes), and offer to make your profile private instead.

Comment: The question is always private to whom? Some sites allow register/paid users additional tools.

Comment: AFAIK, invisible to recruiters and anyone who registers as a company and searches the database for potential candidates.

Comment: I tried removing my info from one site and it accomplished nothing. I still get calls and emails from recruiters, and some make it clear they got my info from that site. It bothers me, but there doesn't seem to be anything I can do about it without legal action, and I have no interest in that. I don't answer calls from people I don't know, so I never talk to them. The emails get deleted with no response. Most of the recruiters seem to be doing mass marketing, because many of the jobs are 3,000 miles away, for stuff I don't even do.

Comment: The only legal action that I'm aware of that you can take would be against the job posting site.  However even that's nebulous as recruiter companies download copies of the data then work from that.  Really the best you can hope for at this time would be to do as mhoran says and remove your info from the job site.  Then wait it out, it'll take a few months.

Comment: Note: As far as I am concerned, it is not rude to hang up on a cold caller.

Comment: I'm still getting contacted via the tagged email address from a resume I had up on Monster for two weeks, 4 years ago.  Once you post a resume on a big job site it's scraped and downloaded into many databases and you lose control.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely you can have any success reporting them to any authority. You initially decided to interview with them, so it's not unreasonable for them to think that they might be able to convince you if they try hard enough.

Instead, keep blocking all calls from this company, and block their emails as well. Once they stop getting responses from you, they'll move on to other more likely candidates (recruiters don't like to waste their time).

In the future, you might wish to refrain from cooperating with a recruiter when you don't actually want to be recruited.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that I put my resume up on a site about 10 years ago, and even though it is "off" my old home phone numbers still "out there." I get calls like once in a blue moon from a recruiter and it still surprises me.

So just note, that once you get on those websites, your email and number goes out into the world. When I posted on job sites, I made certain not to include my phone on any outward visible resume and only submitted a resume with my phone that can be directly given to companies.

Personally I dislike recruiters. I'm still not sure how others get luck from them or if them calling is actually anything good at all. All I know is each time I was contacted by them, they never follow through. I don't politely ask them to not send email. I simply ignore any email that starts with, "I'm a recruiter from..."